# perl array not populating, despite hours of tinkering

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, variable-assignment, subroutine

Um...I have the following code snippet, and was wondering why the second subroutine, `search($$)` fails to yield results...while the first routine, `search_item($$$)`, performs admirably (imo).

```
########################
# generate and return a list of users which match only
# one criteria (eg: eyes=2)
#
# $users is a reference to an array of 6-digit hexidecimal user IDs (eg: 000001, 000002, etc)
# $name is the name of the key (or field) to find (eg: 'eyes')
# $value (eg: 2) is compared with the value stored in the key
# if $value matches what's in the $name'd key, then add the uid to a list

sub search_item($$$) {
  my ($users, $name, $value) = @_;
  my @searched;
  foreach my $uid (@$users) {
    my %ustats = user::getUserStats($uid);
    if ($ustats{$name} eq $value) { push @searched, $uid; }
  }

  return @searched;
}

########################
# generate and return a list of users which match
# many criteria (eg: eyes=2, hair=1, etc)
#
# $users is a reference to an array of user IDs (eg: 000001, 000002, etc)
# $terms is a reference to an array of search terms (eg: $terms[0] = "eyes=2";)
sub search($$) {
  my $users = $_[0]; # an array reference
  my $terms = $_[1]; # an array reference
  my @searched;
  my $first = 1;

  foreach my $term (@$terms) {
    # since @$terms is an array of scalars, in the format of 'name=value' pairs
    my $name = $term; $name =~ s/=(.)*//;
    my $value = $term; $value =~ s/$name=//;

    if ($first) {
      # search the given list reference ($users)
      @searched = search_item($users, $name, $value);
      $first = 0; # set to 0 cause now we gotta use @searched
    } else {
      # otherwise use a reference to @searched
      @searched = search_item(\@searched, $name, $value);
    }
  }

  return @searched;
}
```

i have setup the data so the code should return 1 hit.  the data is correct and underlying functions (eg: `getUserStats($)`) also perform flawlessly.

both user *000001* and *969696* have eyes=2 all others eyes=1 and
user ID *000001* is gender=1, all others gender=0

so...if i write:

```
my @users = getUsers();
foreach my $uid (search_item(\@users, 'eyes', 2)) {
  print "$uid<br>\n";
}
```

i get 2 hits of a total of 6 users in my database (this IS a correct result, of course).  satisfied with those results, I run the `search` routine.

```
my @terms = ('eyes=2', 'gender=1'); # gender=0 is a boy.  1 is a girl
my @sResults = search(\@users, \@terms);
if (@sResults) {
  foreach my $uid (@sResults) {
    print "$uid<br>\n";
  }
} else {
  print "nothing found!<br>\n";
}
```

i always see "nothing found!" when i pray and hope to see "000001" instead... :(

this seems like legit code....so....whud am i doin wrong guys???  am i not derefencing something correctly? or...is the dereferencing / referencing the source of my dilema?  i loath pointers...however incredibly useful :p

Comment: Run it through debugger

Comment: @user3885927 i'm not sure i follow...

Comment: `($name,$value) = split /=/,$term;`

Comment: When in doubt, put print statements everywhere to track what's going on. Track the variables. Eventually one of them will print something you didn't expect. It also helps to make them conditional, based on "if ($debug)" and you can turn debugging on and off.

Comment: @stark - nice.  hadn't thought of that, but ... same results.

Comment: ok, so what i am discerning here is there is nothing wrong with the code itself. it really SHOULD do what I expect?? it's the data?

Comment: To use the debugger, run `perl -d ` *scriptname*. Type `h` within the debugger for a help screen or see https://metacpan.org/pod/perldebug

Comment: i added

    $value =~ s/\n//g;
    $ustats{$name} =~ s/\n//g;

to no avail...

Comment: oh wow. tinkering with the data (a straight text file), i moved the gender=1 line from where it was to the end of the file, clicked save, and all is fine.  that's annoying...could `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` be messing with me?? or maybe (because i copied the source from my linux box to windows), is it the end of line marker differences in OS's??

Comment: Don't use subroutine prototypes. They don't do what you wish they did.

Comment: @Sinan - oh! so prototyping is introducing the problem?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from what you have posted as it is not short, self-contained script that others can run by copying and pasting. If you want others to look at your problem, make it easy on them.

Comment: @JarettLloyd: We need to see the input data together with a short program that demonstrates the problem. Failing that, show your whole program or put it on pastebin.com and give us a link to it 8f it is huge

Comment: apologies for not including the data files.  i figured i had those right!  they are just straight text files, after all.

A list is returned because all i need is the user IDs...not the data attached to the user ID.  The user data is loaded up elsewhere in the script (outside this code).  no need to pass around all that data, when the ID is sufficient.  Perhaps the search function will return more than just a list in the future.  I'm thinking of creating a function that makes the list pretty (insert HTML, and things)....

changing names of my modules and subs to your way? lots of work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does actually work if you pass correct parameters. My best guess is that the strings like `eyes=2` that you're using contain spurious whitespace such as a trailing newline

Here's the test program that I used to work on your subrouitines

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %users = (
    '000001' => { eyes => 2, gender => 1 },
    '000002' => { eyes => 1, gender => 0 },
    '000003' => { eyes => 1, gender => 0 },
    '000004' => { eyes => 1, gender => 0 },
    '969696' => { eyes => 2, gender => 0 },
);

sub user::getUserStats {

    my ( $uid ) = @_;

    %{ $users{$uid} };
}

########################
# generate and return a list of users which match only
# one criteria (eg: eyes=2)
#
# $users is a reference to an array of 6-digit hexidecimal user IDs (eg: 000001, 000002, etc)
# $name is the name of the key (or field) to find (eg: 'eyes')
# $value (eg: 2) is compared with the value stored in the key
# if $value matches what's in the $name'd key, then add the uid to a list

sub search_item($$$) {
    my ( $users, $name, $value ) = @_;
    my @searched;
    foreach my $uid ( @$users ) {
        my %ustats = user::getUserStats( $uid );
        if ( $ustats{$name} eq $value ) { push @searched, $uid; }
    }

    return @searched;
}

########################
# generate and return a list of users which match
# many criteria (eg: eyes=2, hair=1, etc)
#
# $users is a reference to an array of user IDs (eg: 000001, 000002, etc)
# $terms is a reference to an array of search terms (eg: $terms[0] = "eyes=2";)
sub search($$) {
    my $users = $_[0];    # an array reference
    my $terms = $_[1];    # an array reference
    my @searched;
    my $first = 1;

    foreach my $term ( @$terms ) {
        # since @$terms is an array of scalars, in the format of 'name=value' pairs
        my $name = $term;
        $name =~ s/=(.)*//;
        my $value = $term;
        $value =~ s/$name=//;

        if ( $first ) {
            # search the given list reference ($users)
            @searched = search_item( $users, $name, $value );
            $first = 0;    # set to 0 cause now we gotta use @searched
        }
        else {
            # otherwise use a reference to @searched
            @searched = search_item( \@searched, $name, $value );
        }
    }

    return @searched;
}

my $users = [ keys %users ];

say for search( $users, [ 'eyes=2', 'gender=1' ] );
```

#### output

```
000001
```

Here's how I would write similar subroutines that behave identically and take the same parameters, but there is a lot in the design of this application that is less that optimal

```
sub search_item {
    my ( $users, $name, $value ) = @_;

    grep {
        my %ustats = user::getUserStats( $_ );
        $ustats{$name} eq $value;
    } @$users;
}

sub search {
    my ($users, $terms) = @_;
    my @searched;

    for my $term ( @$terms ) {
        my ($name, $value) = split /=/, $term;
        @searched = search_item( $users, $name, $value );
        $users = \@searched;
    }

    @searched;
}
```

but I think `user::getUserStats` should be called `User::get_user_stats` (because Perl reserves capital letters for global identifiers such as package names) and it should return a reference to a hash instead of just a list

Comment: see, now that i really like. thank you, Borodin! I will study your code, and incorporate it.  I think the error was when I copied the text files from linux to windows.  I must have missed an end of line marker in the file...

Comment: the GD package has all kinds of subroutines that do not follow the naming convention suggested by Borodin.  $img->colorAllocate(...) for example.  and perl does not, could not, reserve capital letters for anything...